# stacking two Dell 8024 rack switches 

Tags: networking, switch, dell, ethernet

two Dell powerconnect 8024 (8024, 8024F)- rackmount

how can these be tied togeather? stacked..

this would be used as interface for dedicated LAN

Comment: I have no idea what you want when you say `LAN - DNS, DHCP -`

Comment: sorry for a poor question, corrected now

Comment: Your edit did absolutely nothing to improve the question. If this is because of language difficulties try and get someone to help you word it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can sacrifice some SFP+ ports for stacking capabilities. For only two switches I would uses just two connections, perhaps four depending on workload. As for specifics for configuration, there are plenty of examples in the administrator's manual.

Comment: oh look, when one types "stack powerconnect 8024" into google the first result is an entire whitepaper on the subject http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.community.dell.com%2Ftechcenter%2Fextras%2Fm%2Fwhite_papers%2F20065757%2Fdownload.aspx&ei=LdDOT5uFAaGO2AX9ibDJDA&usg=AFQjCNH7gAuCGUOD77y8QKc7qgKQeJlLig

Comment: To be fair, the key word there is "stack", and if you don't know that term, you probably won't find anything

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff: could you elaborate "for two switches - use two connections'? we are looking at the ability to operate the two switches on same LAN - possible without stacking?

Comment: These are fairly high performance switches, the stacking protocols let them act a single unit (one place for configuration). Multiple cables can be used for redundancy or increased performance. You can manage them separate and just connect them as well. If you're going to have a single broadcast domain/subnet, connect ONE cable from the top switch to the bottom switch and call it a day. When you run into performance bottlenecks down the road, have a more proficient engineer configure redundancy and stacking.